# Visual Studio 2010 : Does a file gets included in my .dll if I am not using #include in my code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include

Here's the scenario:

I am scripting a build system for a VS Solution. To make my solution portable, I am adding custom properties through property manager so that I can define global paths for includes that each project in the solution can inherit from . All is working fine till here.

But for a few projects in my solution, I am also using some third party includes. These third party include folders are currently added through the properties of these project by specifying them in addition to the global includes.

What I would like to do is to take these third party includes outside these projects and put them in my global include folder. This way, I have clean solution with only source code in each project and all the includes are in a global folder.

As a result, the projects which do not need these third party includes will also inherit them since they are in global include folder.

My question is - 
If a project's source code does have a #include for a file but that file is still specified in the additional include directory setting, does it gets pulled in the compilation or not.

If not then I my methods works well. If it does include the file even though the source code is not calling then I get a bloated dll.

Any pointer ? Are there any optimization flags / settings in VS 2010 that I can set to ignore the include files which are not a part of the source code or does the compilation process takes care of it automatically ?

I did try to search for similar questions but did not find one matching closely to my need.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: There are a lot of misconceptions in this question.  Copying include files is a practice you are going to deeply regret some day, there's nothing pretty about the copy getting out of sync with the 3rd party library.  The additional include directory setting does *not* determine what gets included, only the #include directive in the source does that.  It is the linker that determines what gets put in a DLL, the #includes have very little to do with it.

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting that I should keep the 3rd party library tightly linked to the projects ?